# Submitting form without background refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

I apologize if this has been asked before. I searched for about half an hour, but couldn't find an answer.
I have one background image for all my pages.
Is there anyway to make this image not reload, especially on a form submit?

This is my css image. I did the #EDEBED to make it flash gray instead of white, but I would love it if it could just not reload the image at all. I'm coding my pages in php btw (+ some javascript).

```
body
{
    background: #EDEBED url('../background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Comment: if this is js/ajax (php) related, you'll need to post your codes for that. I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but am unable to given only css code.  This for other potential answerers and visitors to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it mattered what code I have on my page. I just want the background to stay and not reload when I do a form submit. Most pages it doesn't matter, but one page I'm reloading an entire puzzle (php code) on every "check answers" button press, which makes the page flash pretty badly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to not refresh when sending a form or when navigating, you might want to use a javascript framework for your frontend. Everytime your page gets refreshed, your background image will be reloaded.

Now I am trying to understand why you would want to prevent the image from reloading. If it is because of saving of data or anything related to performance, you should not worry. Caching is invented for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you want to send form data without refreshing page, then you can try something like this (jQuery/js solution). It will use jQuery to submit form without refrehing page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', /* Methond, can be POST or GET or PUT etc */
    url: $("myFormSelecor").attr("action"), /* URL where to send form data */
    data: $("myFormSelecor").serialize(), /* Form data */
    // If you want, then you can save data in custom format too, like so:
    /*
    data: {
        name: "Name is my name..",
        randomValue: $('#randomInputFieldSelector').val()
    }
    */
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Ajax sent and server responded with:");
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

This requires jQuery to be included on page.
Docs and examples: http://api.jquery.com/

And google hosted jQuery library: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery